# Create a class that contains an array of an object I just defined

Tags: java, arrays, object

Okay, so I just created an object called "house" that draws a house using

```
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D; 
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;".
```

I now want to create an array that can recreate these houses "x" amount of times. How should I go about doing this?

Cheers

Comment: do you mean that you wish to create X instances of the House object? or do you want x houses to be drawn on the screen?

Comment: I would hope this question was more complicated than how to use an array but it seems like that is the question. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Is the question about *limiting* the number of houses that can be created to some specific limit, or simply about creating multiple houses?

Comment: if it's a fixed amount, you can just use Object[]. if you want to change the array dynamically, you can use ArrayList<Object>

Comment: If you've defined a class named House you can create an array of House references with `House[] someHouses = new House[numberOfHouses];`.  Or use one of the List classes.

Comment: Note that none of these approaches will create the House objects themselves -- you must create them with, eg, `someHouses[someIndex] = new House(someParms);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ArrayList to store the Objects in.
As far as the parameters you are using to create the Rectangles, they are not here so I can't help.
Here is a link to an ArrayList

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html